# mysql DECIMAL storage requirements

Tags: mysql

I was reading the mysql manual and want to make sure I understanding something correctly.

If I have DECIMAL (15,8) would this mean 6 digital before the decimal and 8 after?

If I want to move from 15,2 to allow for 8 decimals after price, then should I move to 21,8 so I don't lose any precision?

Comment: Have you read the [manual section on storage requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html)?

Comment: I was asking for clarification. I find it sometimes hard to understand the manual

Comment: I was just asking if you had. It's okay if you need clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From mysql documentation : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html

---

In a DECIMAL column declaration, the precision and scale can be (and usually is) specified; for example:

```
salary DECIMAL(5,2)
```

In this example, **5 is the precision and 2 is the scale**. The precision represents the number of significant digits that are stored for values, and the scale represents the number of digits that can be stored following the decimal point.

Standard SQL requires that DECIMAL(5,2) be able to store any value with five digits and two decimals, so values that can be stored in the salary column **range from -999.99 to 999.99**.